# Ringtone to specific contact

Tags: java, android, audio, ringtone

Edited:1

I'm making an app with sounds and implementing a bit of code I came across the following error to set the sound to a specific contact

this is the code :

```
       Button b7 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b7);
        b7.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
         {

        if (click){
        cp.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        cp.update(0,0,500,500);
        click=false;
        }else{
        cp.dismiss();
        click=true;
        }}
      return click;}});
       b7.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() { 


         public void onClick(View v){




       File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Bizzsound/");
         boolean success = false;
         if (!folder.exists()) {
          success = folder.mkdirs();
         }
         if (!success) {
        } else {
      }



      File direct = new File("/sdcard/Bizzsound/");

      if (!direct.exists()) {
      direct.mkdirs();
        }
       byte[] buffer=null;  
       InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.b1); 
       File dir1 = new File ("/sdcard/Bizzsound/");
         File f1 = new File(dir1, String.format("b1.mp3"));
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int size=0;  

        try {  
        size = fIn.available();  
         buffer = new byte[size];  
         fIn.read(buffer);  
       fIn.close();  
        } catch (IOException e) {  
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
     try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f1);
        fos.write(buffer);  
       fos.flush();
      fos.close();
       bos.close();


   } catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e1.printStackTrace();
      }


      File k = new File("/sdcard/Bizzsound/", "b1.mp3");

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
      values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
       values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "b1.mp3");
       values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
         values.put(AudioColumns.ARTIST, "artist");
        values.put(AudioColumns.IS_RINGTONE, true);
         values.put(AudioColumns.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
         values.put(AudioColumns.IS_ALARM, true);
         values.put(AudioColumns.IS_MUSIC, false);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);





         mpButton1 = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.b1);
         mpButton1.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
         @Override
         public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mpButton1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       mpButton1.start();

       mpButton1.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mpButton1) {
        mpButton1.release();

        };
        });
          }
       });



   }});










            }






 @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

   switch (reqCode) {
   case (PICK_CONTACT):
   if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

    Uri contactData = data.getData();
     Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
      if (c.moveToFirst()) {

       String id = c
        .getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

     Uri localUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, id);

     File k = new File("/sdcard/Bizzsound/", "b1.mp3");
    ContentValues localContentValues = new ContentValues();

String hasPhone = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));



    if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {

       Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query  
(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null);
     phones.moveToFirst();

String cNumber = phones.getString(phones //error at this line
.getColumnIndex("b1.mp3"));
 System.out.println("number is:" + cNumber);
     }

 String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
String SDCardRoot1 = (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/b1.mp3");


localContentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
                                localContentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE,"b1.mp3");
                                localContentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE,"audio/*");
localContentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "");
                                localContentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
localContentValues.put(AudioColumns.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
localContentValues.put(AudioColumns.IS_ALARM, true);
localContentValues.put(AudioColumns.IS_MUSIC, false);
                                localContentValues.put(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, id);
                                localContentValues.put(ContactsContract.Data.CUSTOM_RINGTONE, SDCardRoot1);
 getContentResolver().update(localUri, localContentValues,
null, null);
 Toast.makeText(this, "Ringtone assigned to: " + name, 0).show();
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }

        }
```

Now the phone freezes when receiving the call from the contact and getting this error:
the process com.android.phone has been stopped

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.bizzsound1"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

      <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:largeHeap="true" >



        <activity
            android:name="org.bizzsound1.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>




        <activity     
            android:name="org.bizzsound1.menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="org.bizzsound1.MENU" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>











             <activity android:name="org.bizzsound1.Disclamer"
                 android:screenOrientation="portrait">
             </activity>


 <activity android:name="com.startapp.android.eula.EULAActivity"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />

         <activity android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.list3d.List3DActivity"
android:taskAffinity="altervista.org.gapplication1.AppWall"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme" />
<activity android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.AppWallActivity"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" android:taskAffinity="altervista.org.gapplication1.AppWall"
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />




<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
                  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>






    </application>





</manifest>
```

Comment: `requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS` please read your error logs before asking.

Comment: So may you share the content of your manifest ?

Comment: your code is a/ too long, b/ barely readable. please format it and reduce to a minimum set that allows to reproduce the issue,

Comment: what makes you think b1 is a column ? `getColumnIndex("b1.mp3")` (hint : it is not a column, you cannot get a column index out of it)

Comment: Now you set the sound but crashes the phone, I updated the question